# Leap days calculator code error, Please point out where I am going wrong

Tags: python-3.x

I found this problem in the Daily programming subreddit while practicing Python, this is the link https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/b0nuoh/20190313_challenge_376_intermediate_the_revised/ I cannot seem to get my code working please help me...

```
    def leaps(year_1, year_2):
        number_of_leaps = 0
        if year_1 == year_2:
            return number_of_leaps
        if year_1 % 4 != 0:
            year_1 += 4 - (year_1 % 4)
        if year_1 % 100 == 0:
            if year_1 % 900 == 200 or year_1 % 900 == 600:
                start_year = year_1
            else:
                start_year = year_1 + 4
        else:
            start_year = year_1
        if start_year >= year_2:
            return number_of_leaps
        else:
            for year in range(start_year, year_2, 4):
                if year % 100 == 0:
                    if year % 900 == 200 or year_1 % 900 == 600:
                        number_of_leaps += 1
                else:
                    number_of_leaps += 1
            return number_of_leaps


    print(leaps(1234, 5678))
    print(leaps(123456, 7891011))
```

The actual outputs are supposed to be `1077` and `1881475` respectively but I seem to be getting `1072` and `1872844` please tell me the problem.

Comment: You want the  years to be inclusive or exclusive of the lower and upper limit?

Comment: In my answer below, I have assumed inclusive of lower and exclusive of upper limit

Comment: I want inclusive of lower and exclusive of upper limit

Comment: Then my answer should work for you! Please check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reddit link it is a `revised Julian` calendar, so the logic will be as below

```
def check_leap(year):
    #A leap year is divisible by 4 but not by 100
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    # A leap year leaves 200 or 600 reminder when divided by 900
    if year % 900 == 200 or year % 900 == 600:
        return True
    #All other cases are non leap years
    return False

def leaps(year_1, year_2):
    number_of_leaps = 0
    #If year_1 is bigger than year_2, range is incorrect
    if year_1 > year_2:
        return number_of_leaps

    for year in range(year_1, year_2):
        if(check_leap(year)):
            number_of_leaps+=1

    return number_of_leaps
```

Checking the output, we get.

```
leaps(2016, 2017)
leaps(2019, 2020)
leaps(1900, 1901)
leaps(2000, 2001)
leaps(2800, 2801)
leaps(123456, 123456)
leaps(1234, 5678)
leaps(123456, 7891011)
1
0
0
1
0
0
1077
1881475
```

Comment: I see, that logic was presented in the question so I had been using that. Will try this thanks.

Comment: Great. Please accept and upvote my answer if it helps you :)

Comment: Hi, I saw you unaccepted my answer! Could you let me know if there was an issue in my answer?

Comment: In the reddit post aforementioned there are some different answers which do not seem to match either your answer or mine so i cannot say this is the final answer i still need help ...

Comment: Aah, this is not a standard calendar, but a `revised Julian` calendar, whereas I assumed gregorian! You should have mentioned this important info in the question @DevastatingRPG man!

Comment: I see thanks... am new to Stack Overflow so didnt know what all to mention :)